# Vuetify (Vue + Laravel) Navigation bar active link is not set after a router push

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

I have a quite simple problem but I can't solve it. I used a **navigation drawer** with a **v-list-item-group** and the navigation is functioning fine. Just when I use **router-link** or a **this.$router.push()** the active link is not changing and stays at the previous site.

For example. When the current site is home and a link from there leading to documentations don't rerender the active-link of the **documentations** tab and stays on **home**. If I click it directly in the navigation-bar the active links are set just fine.

[image]

I tried following things:

```
methods:
this.$router.push({
   name: "documentations",
   params: { id: user_id}
});
```

```
methods:
this.$router.replace({
   name: "documentations",
   params: { id: user_id}
});
```

A router link in template with the options exact and exact-path:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'documentations', params: { userId: item.id}}">
```

Does someone experienced a similiar problem? Did I oversee something crucial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with a v-list-item-group

`v-list-item-group` is not supposed to be used with navigation, it's for making selectable lists like this:

[image: 1]

If you just use `v-list` + `v-list-item` it should work.

Comment: Very strange, I took the example from the navigation-bar Documentation (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers/#examples) and it is built with a v-list-item-group. I never would have thought that this is the troublemaker. I now deleted the item-group and set the active-class option on every router-link. Now it is working perfectly fine. Thank you very much!